# Magento edit order comments in admin - order - comments history

Tags: magento

Hope someone can help me, I want to be able to edit and remove comments from admin - sales - orders, comments history. 
It would also need to be updated on the frontend at customer view

Can this be done?

Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom module that extend  `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/history.phtml`

Comment are store in db table `sales_flat_order_status_history`

```
<?php if ($_item->getComment()): ?>
     <br/><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getComment(), array('b','br','strong','i','u')) ?> <a href="{customModule}/delete/id/<?php echo $_item->getId() ?> ">Delete</a> <a href="{customModule}/edit/id/<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>">Edit</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then in your controller you can edit or delete comment

Comment: oh thank I will try to figure out how to do that, sounds a bit complicated  but will try.

thank you!

Comment: Im such a noob at this, could you explain in more detail on how I do this, please.
Thank you for your help